# IF time is between two times return value

Tags: excel, if-statement, time

Why IF formula still returning false even if now time false between user input?

[image]

Comment: Get rid of the format (TIME) and apply GENERAL format. You may see, that the Integer part of the decimal number beneath is outside desired limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the =Now() formula you are getting back the current date and time. The manually entered times represent the time on 1/1/1900.

Change your =Now() formula to

=Now()-Int(Now())

Then it will return the time without the date portion and your comparison will work.